# Single or Multiple Maven pom.xml configuration files?

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I would like to ask these questions related to pom.xml files in Maven projects.

- What is a reason to have multiple `pom.xml` for all dependency libraries instead of having all dependencies in one single `pom.xml`?
- Where should be these `pom.xml` files in Maven project placed?

This is an example of pom.xml for Spring framework - http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.pom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - What is a reason to have multiple pom.xml for all dependency libraries instead of having all dependencies in one single pom.xml?

A maven project can be made of many artifacts.  One artifact may be a String manipulation library.  Another may be a webapp that uses that String manipulation library.

Here's why you shouldn't put all your dependencies in one pom: Your String manipulation library should not have a reference to the servlets.jar just because an unrelated pom is a webapp.  **Each artifact should have only what it *needs* in its classpath.**

(You may be interested to learn about the [dependencyManagement](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) tag, but it does not directly relate to your question.)

> - Where should be these pom.xml files in Maven project placed?

As @MariuszS linked to, here's [the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

> At the top level files descriptive of the project: **a pom.xml file** (and any properties, maven.xml or build.xml if using Ant). In addition, there are textual documents meant for the user to be able to read immediately on receiving the source: README.txt, LICENSE.txt, etc.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my primary language, the best help for me would be to show an example project with multiple pom.xml files, maybe on GitHub? I'll try to find such project and find out its directory structure.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your project, if project is small and product of this project (artifact) is only one then one pom is enough. But if your project have many artifacts (libraries, WARs, EARs etc) then for every artifact pom is required (generally).

Maven concept is that one project definition (POM) generate only one artifact (there are exceptions). Every project should have separate directory with `pom.xml` inside and source directories if needed.

One maven project can build two diffrent apps (for example desktop and webapp). This diffrent applications has diffrents dependencies.

Sample multimodule project structure: https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

### Read more

- [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)
- [Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)
- [Maven by Example 
  Chapter 6. A Multi-module Project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

Comment: I will look at these links deeply. Now I have one simple question - if I have pom.xml files for all libraries where should be these files in project placed?

Comment: Maven has concept of local repository (HOME/.m2/repository). When your project is builded, then library are copied from local repository to your artifact. Libraries are not stored in VCS (SVN, GIT etc)

Comment: Sorry, I meant where should be these multiple pom.xml files placed in Maven project (not libraries' jars, concept of local repository I know).

Comment: Link to sample multimodule project added to answer. `pom.xml` are located in separated directories. Whole project has tree structure.