# Setting for pom.xml under hadoop mapReduce project

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, pom.xml

I created a word count project and import with maven the GeoIP by maxmind(maven) - this Geoip  project is [build with maven](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-java/).

After I import I have a new project(geoIP) next to word count project with a pom.xml (very long) which was created by eclipse .

But in the above link they are saying add to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
    <version>v2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

1. I don't get it if eclipse created pom.xml for me should I delete OR add it with the above code ?
2. How many pom.xml files do I need ?
3. Does MapReduce project needs to be built with maven as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with GeoIP2 but it shouldn't make a difference here.

> if eclipse created pom.xml for me should I delete OR add it with the above code ?

Eclipse created a `pom.xml` file for your *geoip* project by default. You should add your new dependency for your file in order to access GeoIP.

> How many pom.xml files do I need ?

Really depends on your overall project structure. You should probably take a look at the answers of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010009/single-or-multiple-maven-pom-xml-configuration-files) and take a peek at [this example](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle) of multiple maven files for a project.

> Does MapReduce project needs to be built with maven as well ?

Nope but I would recommend it, it makes your life easier. Here are my dependencies for Map-Reduce Jobs:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- junit testing framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hadoop hdfs components -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hadoop map-reduce components -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hadoop common components -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

With all additional dependencies located in the [Maven Repository for Hadoop](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop).